# iOS 7 issue: viewDidDisappear not being called after viewWillDisappear

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

The problem I am experiencing is that when i try to pop a view controller using the default back `swipeGesture` in iOS7 `viewDidDisappear` of the present `ViewController` does not always get called after `viewWillDisappear`. I am using the `UINavigationController` as `rootViewController`.

App remain struck and does not receive any user inputs after this scenario. Sometimes app gets crashed, when i look at the log: it shows "Can't add self as `subview`' and in crash log, it showss `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`. How to fix this, but when i use back button in navigation bar app works normally.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
//            [self.navigationController.navigationBar setAlpha:1.0f];
    [self createBarButtonITems];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Back";
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self zoomOutTableWithoutAnimation];
}

-(void)zoomOutTableWithoutAnimation
{
    backgroundView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,480);
    backgroundView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(1, 1);

    sideMenuTableView.transform=CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.5,0.5);
    sideMenuTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0,150,self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height);
    sideMenuTableView.hidden = YES;
}
```

Comment: post your code what you have tried

Comment: Go to 'edit schemes' and check the 'Enable Zombie Objects' in the diagnostics tab. It will help you to debug the BAD_ACCESS crash.

Comment: Dont forget to call [super viewWillDisappear:animated]; in - (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{}

Comment: i have edited my code and included zooOutTableWithoutAnimation methd

Comment: @coverback, in that method I'm just changing the frames of views.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned swipe back gesture, this is probably due to the interactive pop back.
As it is mentioned in WWDC 2013, session **Custom Transitions Using View Controllers**, you cannot assume a viewWillDisappear will be followed by viewDidDisappear. The same goes to viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear.

I'm not sure why you want to call 
    **[self createBarButtonITems]**
in viewWillDisappear, did you mean viewWillAppear?
Anyway, it seems to me that **[self createBarButtonITems]** did some side effect.

Try the following code in viewWillDisappear to undo the side effect:

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear
{
   [self doSomethingHasSideEffect];
   id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator> coordinator;
        coordinator = [self transitionCoordinator];
        if(coordinator && [coordinator initiallyInteractive]) 
        {
            [coordinator notifyWhenInteractionEndsUsingBlock:
             ^(id <UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinatorContext> ctx) 
             {
                 if(ctx.isCancelled) 
                 {
                     [self undoAnySideEffect]
                 }
             }]; 
        }
}
```

Comment: You cannot assume a `viewDidDisappear` only if the user cancels the interactive pop gesture.

Comment: @sbhhbs, could you explain what this  [self undoAnySideEffect] do?

Answer (score 0):

From your code what I can understand is you need a back button with title @"Back" instead of the previous view controllers title

just add this code tho your view controller, in which you trying to do the above stuff  view did load method

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:(IS_IOS_7 ? @"" : @"Back") style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:Nil action:nil];
self..navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self createBarButtonITems];
    self.navigationItem.title = @"Back";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i will try this and let you know the status.